# Passing through console output from Process.Start directly

Tags: .net, f#

I'm using [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from a .NET command-line application to run another command-line application. I don't want to capture the output of the application, I just want it to go to the console directly.

With the program below the output seems to just disappear into thin air. If I leave [`CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at the default `false` then I do get the output in a fresh console window, but I want it in the original console window. [`UseShellExecute <- false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is also needed otherwise `CreateNoWindow` is forced to `false`.

I could do something much more complicated using [`RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`RedirectStandardError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then capturing the output and re-printing it, but this is fiddly in combination with [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), particularly as in my real application I want to use [the version that has a timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Is there any way I can simply get the standard output and error passed through directly?

The behaviour I am seeing is confusing because the documentation for `RedirectStandardOutput` does seem to say clearly:

> When a Process writes text to its standard stream, that text is typically displayed on the console.

Here's the demonstration code. When I run it with `DummyRunner.exe` I get the output from the first bit of code, and when I run it with `DummyRunner.exe DummyRunner.exe` I get nothing. Although the code is in F# there's nothing particularly F# specific about this problem that I know of.

```
module DummyRunner

open System
open System.Diagnostics

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =

    // do something when called with no arguments, just so we can call
    // this with itself as an argument to make a self-contained test
    if args.Length = 0 then
        for n = 1 to 5 do
            printfn "Waiting %d" n
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        System.Environment.Exit(0)

    let cmd = args.[0]
    let cmdArgs = args.[1..]

    let startInfo = ProcessStartInfo(cmd, String.Join(" ", cmdArgs))

    startInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow <- true

    let p = Process.Start(startInfo)

    p.WaitForExit()
    p.ExitCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually reading the standard output of your process.  Redirecting the standard output adds the output to the process standard output, but does not read it into your running process.

```
let startInfo = ProcessStartInfo(cmd, String.Join(" ", cmdArgs))

startInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true;
let p = Process.Start(startInfo)

printfn p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit()
p.ExitCode
```

this should forward the output from the running process to the parent running thread.  See this page for more information on this.

[redirect std output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to read the standard output, I just want it to go straight to the console.

Comment: the above change pipes the std output of one process to the std output of the other, yes technically it does read the output of one process into the other, but i'm not entirely sure it is possible for two processes to share the same std output stream without reading from one to the other.  There may be a way to do this internally, but i suspect further research will find that it is done the same way

Comment: to avoid the deadlock you could make the read async, and then if the wait for exit does timeout the async call still returns...

Comment: I'd also need to interleave with reading the standard error - I can't use `ReadToEnd` on both streams simultaneously unless I use multiple threads. I'm sure I could make things work that way, but it seems quite complex.

Comment: the BeginOutputReadLine method mentioned in the link i gave you is an async read on the std output stream of the called process, you are correct you cannot use sync reads on both, but you certainly can use the async reads

Comment: I see, so I could hook it up in an event-driven way, which should be fairly simple and safe. Thanks - I'd missed that this was possible, although as I said in the question I'd still rather do without having to set `RedirectStandardOutput` at all.