# Getting CMD output from a a shell using Process

Tags: c#, shell, process, cmd, output

I don't know weather if this question has an answer or not ... 
I know that to get the output of CMD process using C# can be done easily using these lines :

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.sh",
        Arguments = string.Format(@"net use {0} && dir {0}", path),
        UseShellExecute = false,    ///this is the problem
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    });
```

My problem is I want to run a shell script instead of .exe file but when I set `UseShellExecute`to false I got a dummy output from the shell and the shell script doesn't work properly  ... So, Are there any way or suggestions to handle such a thing ?

Comment: Are you using `Process.StandardOutput` to read the output from the process?

Comment: @fourpastmidnight yes, sir

Comment: Could the verbatim string operator (`@`) be "un-escaping" the braces in the `string.Format` call (but then, I'd think you'd get a `FormatException`)? Try removing the `@` in the call to `string.Format`.

Comment: Let's start with this question: please update your post to show us the "dummy output" that you receive. This may help us identify the issue.

Comment: What I meant with the dummy output is that the process doesn't give the correct results I think it doesn't even run when I remove the code responsible for output the process result to a string, it works fine

Comment: I used string.Format but nothing new

Comment: For another thing, the built in `cmd.exe` command interpreter in Windows does not understand the `.sh` extension for shell scripts. It only understands `*.bat` and `*.cmd` scripts.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight I have another .bat file and the same problem occurs

Comment: Here's an [SO question with answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366967/passing-through-console-output-from-process-start-directly) similar to your own (though, in F#, but I was able to understand it). Hope that helps you.